# Data in my service isn't persistent across my angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, singleton, persistent

I have two controllers. The first one sets a variable into my service and my second one is supposed to get this variable, but it's undefined. 
Aren't angular services supposed to be singletons ? Because my service seems to be instantiated for each controller.

Here's my code :

**First controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'User', function ($scope, User) {
    $scope.join = function () {
        User.setRoom("test");
        console.log(User.getRoom()); // displays 'test'
        $window.location.href = '/talk';
    }
}]);
```

In my second controller, I've just a

```
console.log(User.getRoom()); // displays ''
```

And here's my **service**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('User', function () {
    var data = {
        room: ''
    };
    return {
        getRoom: function () {
            return data.room;
        },
        setRoom: function (room) {
            data.room = room;
        }
    };
});
```

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$window.location.href = '/talk';` to navigate - this triggers a full page reload, and all services are therefore also reinitialized.

You probably want to use the $location service. See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) and/or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267570/5115774) for a summary of the difference between the two.